How much must one do to fulfill the mitzvah of bikur cholim?
In Ahavas Chesed Chelek Gimmel Perek Beis, the Chofetz Chaim discusses the Mitzvah of Bikur Cholim and how people בעוונותינו הרבים העולם מקלין במצוה זו.
He also writes there that:
מצות ביקור חולים אין לו שעור ... אפילו כמה פעמים ביום
What is the גדר for how many visits one should make to the sick person?
The Chofetz Chaim talks about multiple times per day, does that mean one must do so at least once a day? What if the person is an hour drive away, how much effort or how often must the visit.
Is there any distance at which someone doesn't have to make an effort to visit the sick person?

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in סימן קצג - הלכות בקור חולים highlights the main purpose of Bikur Cholim. Dropping in & out for a few seconds is not the idea.
The main purposes are:

כַּמָּה פְעָמִים בַּיוֹם. וְכָל הַמּוֹסִיף, הֲרֵי זֶה מְשֻׁבָּח, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁלֹּא יִהְיֶה לָטֹרַח עַל הַחוֹלֶה.‏

As you mentioned, go often if possible, but ensure you're not being a burden on the patient. (I would add: or their caretakers.)
Going too often to the point that they have to entertain you, is counterproductive. Being there when the Doctors make their rounds or a favorite friend or family member is there is not a great idea.

עִקַּר מִצְוַת בִּקּוּר חוֹלִים הוּא לְעַיֵן בְּצָרְכֵי הַחוֹלֶה מַה הוּא צָרִיךְ לַעֲשׂוֹת לוֹ, וְשֶׁיִמְצָא נַחַת רוּחַ עִם חֲבֵרָיו, וְגַם שֶׁיִתֵּן דַעְתּוֹ עָלָיו וִיבַקֵּשׁ רַחֲמִים עָלָיו. וְאִם בִּקֵּר וְלֹא בִקֵּשׁ, לֹא קִיֵם אֶת הַמִּצְוָה.‏

The main purpose of your visit should be to see how you can be of assistance. Maybe a caretaker needs a ride, or a bill to be paid or some shopping or food. Possibly bring something to read for the patient or the caretakers.
It should be a pleasant visit; make sure the patient is enjoying themselves because you're there. Keep the mood light, or learn with them if that's what they want. Or sing or discuss sports - but make sure the patient is enjoying it, not just smiling to make the visitor feel good. Maybe prepare a fun story or some good news.
Don't forget to pray for the patient. In their presence it can be in any language and you don't need their full name. "Please Hashem let my buddy lying here have a swift & full recovery". Not davening defeats the purpose

הַמְבַקְּרִים יְדַבְּרוּ אִתּוֹ בְּהַשְׂכֵּל וָדַעַת, וְיֹאמְרוּ לוֹ, דְבָרִים מְחַיִּים, וְלֹא דְבָרִים מְמִיתִים. וְיֹאמְרוּ לוֹ, שֶׁיִתֵּן דַּעְתּוֹ עַל עִנְיָנָיו, אִם הִלְוָה אוֹ הִפְקִיד אֵצֶל אֲחֵרִים אוֹ אֲחֵרִים אֶצְלוֹ, וְאַל יְפַחֵד מִפְּנֵי זֶה מֵהַמָּוֶת.‏

The mood should be positive and upbeat; not morbid. That said, for terminally ill patients it may be appropriate to discuss his will and last testament, debts and POAs. But only if you are the right person in the right place.
You are supposed to be of assistance and not trying to dig into their private affairs.
Discussing how death is a rebirth into a better world is appropriate, if you're well-versed in the subject matter and can do it nicely.
So there's no fixed rules for how often to go. But if going daily means the patient feels bad that you're spending most of your free time visiting them, then maybe you're going too often.
As long as you're being helpful, and the patient is thrilled to see you, you're doing it right.
